# different popup depending on what div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the following code that is working fine to open a popup

```
  $(".moreMessages").click(function(){
      showPopup();
    });
    $(".popup-background").click(function(){
      hidePopup();
    });
    function showPopup(){
      $(".js-popup").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
      $("body").addClass('u-noscroll');
    }
    function hidePopup(){
      $(".js-popup").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
      });
      $("body").removeClass('u-noscroll');
    }
```

Now i'm having 3 elements

```
<div class="moreMessages moreMessages--channels"><span>+5 more...</span></div>
  <div class="moreMessages moreMessages--direct"><span>+5 more...</span></div>
  <div class="moreMessages moreMessages--groups"><span>+5 more...</span></div>
```

What i'm willing to do is see on with one is clicked to show different content in my popup.

so for example if you click on the first one this needs to happen

```
 $(".moreMessages--channels").addClass('active');
```

and on closing it also needs to be removed

```
 $(".moreMessages--channels").removeClass('active');
```

So how can I get the class were is clicked on and use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine if the clicked on element has a specific class in the following way:

```js
$('.a').click(function() {

  var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  
  $.each(classes, function(index, item) {
    if (item === 'b-a') {
      
      // open a popup?
      // OR, populate a single popup element with new text...
      
      alert("b-a text!")
    }
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: dashed 2px teal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a b-a"></div>
```

It would probably be easier to have just *one* pop up and populate the text differently based on what class is found (eg `if(thisClass === 'moreMessages--channels) { // do something; }`)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the class by using `this`. Inside the function, `this` will be the object that triggered the click event, so knowing the class would be as easy as:

```
$(this).attr("class");
```

And it would be enough for adding/removing the "active" class, without even worrying about the object's original class:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for you?

```
$(".moreMessages").click(function(){
    showPopup();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#content').append($(this).html());
});


$('#close').click(function(){
    hidePopup();
});

$(".popup-background").click(function(){
    hidePopup();
});

function showPopup(){
    $(".js-popup").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $("body").addClass('u-noscroll');
}
function hidePopup(){
    $(".js-popup").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $("body").removeClass('u-noscroll');
    $(".moreMessages").removeClass("active");
    $('#content').html("");
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h2hcpcee/1/